# Visualize received audio

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I want to create a Siri like effect(using this library https://github.com/caffeinalab/siriwavejs) for VOIP calls.

I'm working on a webapp using https://webrtc.org/ to generate a VOIP call session.

I'm basically following this tutorial https://webrtc.ecl.ntt.com/en/js-tutorial.html the call is fine and I can get the audio and the connection. What I don't know is how to extract information from the Audio Stream. For example if I want to get my sound levels(volume) or other party sound level(volume) so that I can pass it to the library as an amplitude.

Basically I want to extract the volume level and the speed level. So that I can pass them to the library.

I tried reading about the AudioContext APIs but can't find a place to get these information from.

Comment: Have you looked at [getStats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpReceiver/getStats) and the [getstats npm package](https://github.com/muaz-khan/getStats)?

Comment: @kontrollanten I read about it but it doesn't seem to return the volume level for example

Comment: You'll get the audioInputLevel from audioStreams, checkout getstats npm package for an example